# SYNTAX: Using PHP function within SQL UPDATE query

Tags: php, sql

I want to use my custom PHP function CalculateAge which takes 3 parameters (day, month and year) inside a SQL UPDATE. However, I need to pass the SQL variables to the function, and I don't know how to do it. Here's what it looks like (note that bday, bmonth and byear are "users" table columns).

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET age=".CalculateAge(bday,bmonth,byear)."");
```

Comment: You can not do it. PHP sends request to MySQL server as a string, and this string 'knows' nothing about your PHP functions. It only consists of the 'text' that you will put in it. Tell us what that function is doing - it may be possible to do the same things by SQL requests.

Comment: Another way - implement stored function inside database. Look at [Stored routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the mysql values into the function like that.  You would have to do a `SELECT` to get the values, fetch the row, pass them into the function, and then `INSERT` that value.

I would suggest that instead of updating the age, you should store the person's birthday since it never changes.  When you want to show their age, just do the math.

Answer (score 1):

You can't interweave PHP functions in a query. You'd need to first query for the data in each row; calculate the result values for each row, and then run queries to update each row based on the results.

Answer (score 1):

first retrieve data from database:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT bday,bmonth,byear FROM users");
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
```

now call your php function `$age=CalculateAge($info['bday'],$info['bmonth'],$info['byear']);`
and then update table... .

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET age=".$age."");
```